# Typescript complains about e: EventTarget not having "value" property in onChange function if I pass it as forwarded prop through wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a component called [**SelectField**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shtern-xle91b?file=/src/SelectField.tsx) which is a wrapper that renders label, helper text and select input inside (inspired by [**TextField**](https://mui.com/api/text-field/) @material-UI).

**SelectField** exposes `value` & `onChange` props and forwards them to an internal select component.
It also exposes `selectProps` prop which you can also use to pass props to the internal select:

```
// SelectField.tsx
type SelectFieldProps = {
  ...
  selectProps?: SelectProps;
  value?: SelectProps["value"];
  onChange?: SelectProps["onChange"];
}

const SelectField = ({
  value,
  onChange,
  selectProps
}: SelectFieldProps) => {
  const props = {
    value,
    onChange,
    ...selectProps,
  }

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Label>select</Label>

      <select {...selectProps} />
    </FormControl>
  )
}


// Now the question part...


// App.tsx

// case 1
<SelectField
  options={options}
  selectProps={{
    value,
    // Line below works as expected, no typescript errors
    onChange: (e) => setValue(e.target.value as string)
  }}
/>

// case 2
<SelectField
  options={options}
  value={value}

  // Line below gives following error:
  // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget | (EventTarget & 
  // HTMLInputElement) | (EventTarget & { value: unknown; name: string; })'.
  // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)
  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value as string)}
/>
```

Why does typescript complain about event.target not having "value" property in the second case, but not in the first?
From what I've understood in both cases event argument should have the same type, no?

Here is codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shtern-xle91b?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Props` of `SelectField` has `& FormControlProps` which has its own `onChange` type, so the final `onChange` becomes a union type.

You can omit the unnecessary `onChange` using  `Omit<FormControlProps, "onChange">`

[image: Edit affectionate-sky-88xj13]